# Бот не реагирует на Inline кнопки

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

При нажатии на кнопку бот не реагирует, что тут не так?

```py
import telebot 
from telebot import types 
bot = telebot.TeleBot('my_token') 
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def start(msg): 
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() 
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='1')) 
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Hey', reply_markup=markup) 
 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True) 
def callback_handler(call): 
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text="Вы нажали кнопку ") 
 
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: попробоавать обробатывать if call.data == '1':

Comment: Всё равно не реагирует

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot 
from telebot import types 
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен') 
 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def start(msg): 
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() 
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='1')) 
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Hey', reply_markup=markup) 
 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True) 
def callback_handler(call): 
    if call.data == '1':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, text="Вы нажали кнопку 1") 
 
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

[image: вот так должно быть]